# Spring data JPA - The encapsulated expression is not a valid expressio

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While running the below query to get the latest message with the latest data  using the createdOn column
i get the below error

```
select count(m) from MessageWorkFlowStatus  mwfs1 where mwfs1.createdOn =(select max(createdOn) from  MessageWorkFlowStatus mwfs2 where mwfs1.status= 'NEW' or mwfs1.status='IN PROGRESS')
```

The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression

Please let me know if i can run Query this way

Comment: What is count(m) ? try with count(mwfs1)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `count(m)` is not correct. It should either be `count(*)` or `count(mwfs1)`. Secondly, in your inner query, you are using status column from the outer query table (mswfs1) which is logically wrong. It should instead be `mwfs2.status = 'NEW' or mwfs2.status = 'IN PROGRESS'`.

I think your query should be:

```
select count(mwfs1)
from MessageWorkFlowStatus mwfs1
where mwfs1.createdOn = (
    select max(createdOn)
    from MessageWorkFlowStatus mwfs2
    where mwfs2.status= 'NEW' or mwfs2.status='IN PROGRESS')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , i resolved this by comparator in the DTO layer